# How can we hide 'Home' and 'Update License buttons in Excel backstage view?

Tags: excel-365, custom-ui

I am administering an environment that will allow users to edit workbooks in Office 365 Excel.  I don't want to allow the user to have access to any options in the File tab (backstage view) other than 'Print'.  I have successfully hidden most of them using a customUI. However, I can not find idMso's for the 'Update License' button which is included in the latest builds, also the 'Home' button.

This is the normal UI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMJUp.png)

I have added the customUI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv2zu.png)

Which gets me here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdx0M.png)

However I have been unsuccessful in finding idMso for the remaining 'Home' and 'Update License' buttons (as stated previously 'Print' is left accessible by design).

Does anyone have an idea where or how I can find the control id's for these buttons?